# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined sending array from node to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I'm rendering jade from node by this

```
router.get("/register", function (req, res) {
    var countries = [1, 2, 3];
    res.render("./account/register", {
        countries: countries
    });
});
```

and here is my jade template

```
extends ../layout
block content   
    each val,t in countries
        p= val
```

and it gets error  Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
i'm using express 4x, I'm trying to solve this problem almost 2 days

Comment: Please check path of the rendering file. Also, make sure indentation is correct in Jade file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be like:

```
res.render("./account/register", {
        "countries": countries
    });
```

key of JSON should be in quotes.

Comment: Quotes make absolutely no difference in this piece of code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had the problem on Chromium and Opera but not on Firefox. It was some error in Jade involving Template inheritance.
Without inheritance works on.

After changing to [Pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug) everything works fine (see: [Pug with Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)).

Comment: Another reason for such error can be "just" one additional space before new line in jade template - just indentation mismatch.